Glyph renders in Chrome but not rendering in Firefox
Example:


document.getElementById('test').textContent = '12345' + '\x88' + '6789';
#test {
  font-family: tcrm1000;
  font-size:24pt
}

@font-face { 
  font-family: "tcrm1000";
  src: url(data:application/octet-stream;base64,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);
}
<span id="test"></span>



\x88 encodes the glyph • in the font.
It renders in Chrome:

but doesn't render in Firefox:

Is there anything I can do to fix it?
Thanks

About the font:
Typing \item fails to render in https://tex.rossprogram.org/ because of missing font tcrm1000 which is the default font of \textbullet, so I need to convert the font tcrm1000.mf with TS1Encoding to .woff, I found that it is contained in sfrm1000.pfb, then I extracted glyphs from it and I re-encoded to TS1Encoding and generated .woff using FontForge  and write in base64 CSS as above
